# missing some shadow in render result

Tags: shadows

I found out my render result and viewport rendering preview are different, my render result missing some shadow. I've checked and ensure the missing shadow is caused by viewport shading. Please help me QQ thank you
here is the picture with viewport preview and render result
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe help with some screenshots, specifications (Eevee? Cycles?) even maybe share your file (or a part of it): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: hi, I just upload it :D I forgot it

Comment: could ypu please share your file?

Comment: here is the file link, sorry I don't know how to upload a file in here 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IqP2FLanIFoK19vrMkwtG5i7noqmgK9d/view?usp=sharing

Comment: no problem but your way of sharing the file works too ;)